# Rails 4.1 enum and has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, enums, has-many

Is there a way to associate multiple enum values to a model in Rails 4.1 enum or do I have to do it via bit masking (http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association?view=asciicast)? I have a property that I want to keep static (I started off as having it another model but because of a legacy app need to keep the ids static and unchanging) but need to be able to associate multiple to a model.

To be clear: using an enum in Rails 4.1 is very simple (look up any ActiveRecord enum example ie state machine) -- I'm looking to have a model have many enum -- ie much like one can have many of another model (ie a Product has_many DeviceLocations or a Vehicle has_many Tires).  I'd like the has_many to be from a static enum rather than an editable / deletable model.

Comment: Your question is not clear..Can you please add some example to explain it..

Comment: That's not what `enum` is for. You're basically talking about tagging. You should set up another table and a many-to-many relationship with your model via a `has_many, through`, or consider one of the many tagging libraries out there.

Comment: I don't think I agree; the ActiveRecord:Enum was added for something that might be similar to tagging (ie another model that needs no other data) but it seems to be made for more STATIC that would require in-code editing of a model in order to change but is more constant than tagging.

Comment: @grimmwerks:  I think I may have the same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707774/move-static-data-from-db-into-code-in-rails-3 . Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @robd - I did end up using the bitmasking technique: https://gist.github.com/grimmwerks/8ea0985817fb90bf4388