# Move static data from db into code in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say I have a simple scenario with 2 models, `Book`s and `Category`s, where each book has and belongs to many categories.

I want to move the `Category` data out of the database as per [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/extract-mostly-constant-data-from-the-database) and [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/dont-be-normal).

My category class looks like this:

```
class Category
  FICTION = Category.new(1, 'Fiction')
  NON_FICTION = Category.new(2, 'Non Fiction')
  CONTUTERS = Category.new(3, 'Contuters')

  def initialize(id, name)
    @id = id
    @name = name
  end
end
```

I have a `books_categories` table like this:

```
| book_id | category_id |
| 1       | 1           |
| 2       | 3           |
| 3       | 1           |
| 3       | 2           |
...
```

How should I model this in my book class, and in the db?

Ideally, I'd like it to look like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
end
```

But where the book can be added or removed from categories.

One approach would be to be to use [embedded associations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association). The thing I don't like about this is that it makes the db hard to inspect.

Are there any other approaches, perhaps maintaining the existing `books_categories` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at https://github.com/pboling/flag_shih_tzu, but in the end, I implemented this with a simple `has_many` join model. I added an `id` column to the `books_categories` table, renamed to `book_categories` and implemented custom getters / setters on `Book`:

```
class Category
  ALL = [
    FICTION = Category.new(1, 'Fiction'),
    NON_FICTION = Category.new(2, 'Non Fiction'),
    CONTUTERS = Category.new(3, 'Contuters'),
  ]

  CATEGORIES_BY_ID = ALL.index_by(&:id)

  def initialize(id, name)
    @id = id
    @name = name
  end
end

class BookCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  def category
    Category::CATEGORIES_BY_ID[category_id]
  end
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_categories, :autosave => true

  def categories
    book_categories.map(&:category)
  end

  def category_ids
    book_categories.map(&:category_id)
  end

  def category_ids=(ids)
    ids = ids.reject(&:blank?)

    book_categories.each do |book_category|
      book_category.mark_for_destruction unless ids.include?(book_category.id)
    end
    (ids - category_ids).each do |new_id|
      book_categories.build(category_id: new_id)
    end
  end
end
```